# VideoView is not working properly in android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-videoview

When I add a video to android studio then I run the emulator, the video doesn't work well, only the sound works but there is no motion in the video, like it's freezed

Comment: Perhaps you can show the piece of code where VideoView is implemented?

Comment: I guess you probably missing videoView.setZOrderOnTop(true). But Post some code on your videoView to get exact help.